# How can I show the documents of a document set in an InfoPath form?

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have an InfoPath form with a connection to a document library that holds document sets. I have the ID of the specific document set.
How can I make the InfoPath form display Links to the documents of that Document set?

Answer (score 1):

Credit:

[Mano Mangaldas](http://www.blogger.com/profile/04463010398183548997)

http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/12/programmatically-create-document-set.html

This doesnt create the link in InfoPath, but since you haven't recieved any answers maybe this will give you or someone else a jumping off point.

```
public static SPFile CreateDocumentLink(this SPList list, string documentName, string documentUrl, DocumentSet docSet)
{
  SPFile file = null;
  SPListItem item = null;
  if (list is SPDocumentLibrary)
  {
   SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)list;
   if (docLib.ContentTypesEnabled)
   {
    SPContentType myCType = list.ContentTypes["Link to a Document"];
    if (myCType != null)
    {
       //replace string template with values
     string redirectAspx = RedirectAspxPage();
     redirectAspx.Replace("{0}", documentUrl);
       //should change the name of the .aspx file per item
     file = docSet.Folder.Files.Add(documentName + ".aspx", UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(redirectAspx));
       //set list item properties
     item = file.Item;
         item["ContentTypeId"] = myCType.Id;
     item.Update();
       if (item["ContentType"].ToString() == "Link to a Document")
     {
      SPFieldUrlValue fieldUrl = new SPFieldUrlValue()
      { Description = documentName, Url = documentUrl };
        item["URL"] = fieldUrl;
      item.Update();
     }
    }
   }
  }
    return file;
 }
   public static string RedirectAspxPage()
 {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.Append("<%@ Assembly Name='Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' %>");
  builder.Append("<%@ Register TagPrefix='SharePoint' Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls' Assembly='Microsoft.SharePoint' %>");
  builder.Append("<%@ Import Namespace='System.IO' %>");
  builder.Append("<%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint' %>");
  builder.Append("<%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities' %>");
  builder.Append("<%@ Import Namespace='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls' %>");   builder.Append("<html xmlns:mso=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:msdt=\"uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882\">");  builder.Append("<head>");
  builder.Append("<meta name=\"WebPartPageExpansion\" content=\"full\" /> <meta name='progid' content='SharePoint.Link' /> ");
  builder.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix=\"mso:\" FieldList=\"FileLeafRef,URL\"><xml>");
  builder.Append("<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>");
  builder.Append("<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt=\"string\">0x01010A00DC3917D9FAD55147B56FF78B40FF3ABB</mso:ContentTypeId>");
builder.Append("<mso:IconOverlay msdt:dt=\"string\">|docx|linkoverlay.gif</mso:IconOverlay>");  builder.Append("<mso:URL msdt:dt=\"string\">{0}, {0}</mso:URL>");
  builder.Append("</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>");
  builder.Append("</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->");
  builder.Append("</head>");  builder.Append("<body>");
  builder.Append("<form id='Form1' runat='server'>");
  builder.Append("<SharePoint:UrlRedirector id='Redirector1' runat='server' />");
  builder.Append("</form>");  builder.Append("</body>");  builder.Append("</html>");
  return builder.ToString();
 }
```